# Can i connect two routers together wirelessly?

Tags: networking

I want to connect two different router together wirelessly, the first one is DLink and the other is TP-LINK.

Can i do that?

I heard about the bridge mode and the repeater. Could any one help me please.

My TP-LINK router :http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=219&model=TD-W8961ND 
and here is the Dlink :http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=353

Comment: this is off topic and doesn't belong here. Sometimes routers will bridge together sometimes they wont. It's most likely to work if they are the same model, different manufacturers is anyone's guess, and in my experience often doesn't work. You'll have to try it.